# spring gs rest service complete

Tags: spring, rest, service

I try to export spring restful web service as war from eclipse.
When I try to export it I dont't have option to choose the rest project/ spring doesn't see it as war.
It is default project import->spring getting started project->Rest service
Has anybody solution?

Comment: Don't export it as a war, use the build tools (either maven or gradle) for that.

Comment: Problem is that I don't know how to use it? I need it to export project at web server.